# php register system error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp, registration, php

i am trying to make a registration page in php by using xampp but i have a problem. when i run my php file,it gives the following error:

> Notice: Undefined index: UserName in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on
>   line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: UserSurname in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php
>   on line 4
>
> Notice: Undefined index: UserMail in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on
>   line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: UserPassword in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php
>   on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: UserTel in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on
>   line 7
>
> Warning: require(class.phpmailer.php) [function.require]: failed to
>   open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php
>   on line 24
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'class.phpmailer.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\register.php on line 24

my php file, register.php:

```
  <?php
$username=$_POST['UserName'];
$usersurname=$_POST['UserSurname'];
$usermail=$_POST['UserMail'];
$userpass=$_POST['UserPassword'];
$usertelephone=$_POST['UserTel']; 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","rockenpeace");
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("dbe", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (UserName,UserSurname,UserMail, UserPassword, UserTel) 
        VALUES('$username','$usersurname','$usermail','$userpass','$usertelephone')");

mysql_close($con);

try
{
    require("class.phpmailer.php");
    $mail = new PHPMailer();   
    $mail->IsSMTP();
    $mail->Mailer = "smtp";
    $mail->Host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->CharSet="utf-8";
    $mail->Username = "user@gmail.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";
    $mail->From     = "user@gmail.com";
    $mail->FromName="DBE Yazılım";
    $mail->AddAddress($_POST['usermail']); 
    $mail->Subject  = "Registration Information";
    $mail->Body     = "Hello your password is " . $userpass;
    //$mail->AddAttachment($path);
    $mail->Send();
    echo 'Message has been sent.';  
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo 'hata'.$e->getMessage();
}
header("location:confirmation.php"); ?>
```

and in my html page:

```
<input type="text" name="UserMail" id="UserMail" size="30" />   
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" size="30" />   
<input type="text" name="UserSurname" id="UserSurname" size="30" /> 
<input type="text" name="UserTel" id="UserTel" size="30" /> 
<input type="password" name="UserPassword" id="UserPassword" size="30" />
```

Comment: when i run print_r($_POST) in php, it writes Array ( ) . sorry i am beginner for php.so if i am making mistake, warn me.

Comment: You've just given the whole of SO your smtp information. I edited it out for you.

Comment: if it's writing Array ( ) then no form data has been passed to it. You should show us your markup too.

Comment: @Martin Too bad it's still in the revision history... =)

Comment: sorry i couldn't add whole html markup.. :) but i have added input tags in my html page : <input type="text" name="UserMail" id="UserMail" size="30" />   
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" size="30" />  
<input type="text" name="UserSurname" id="UserSurname" size="30" />   
<input type="text" name="UserTel" id="UserTel" size="30" />   
<input type="password" name="UserPassword" id="UserPassword" size="30" />

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like

a) your `$_POST` superglobal is empty (or at least doesn't contain what you think it does). This is the first thing to suspect in a case like this. Run `print_r($_POST)` to see what's in it.

It's never safe to *assume* POST/GET vars are coming in. Check this via `isset()` and also check that they contain what you think they should. In short, we're talking validation.

b) it sounds like the path to your includes is wrong. Again, this is easily checked. Run `echo file_exists('path/to/include')` - if you don't see `1`, the path is wrong

Comment: when i run echo file_exists('path/to/include'), i don't see anything that changes.

Comment: If `file_exists(...)` doesn't output `1` then the path to the file is wrong, as I say

Answer (score 0):

Use [`isset`](http://php.net/isset) to verify the keys exist in the $_POST array.

As for your failed include it means the file isn't in your [`get_include_path`](http://php.net/get_include_path) so you can either set it with [`set_include_path`](http://php.net/set_include_path) (**Note** this may affect your other relative includes), or you can use an `absolute path`.

Finally, use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) on your input variables otherwise you're highly vulnerable to `SQL injection`.

**Sample**

```
if (!isset($_POST['userName'], $_POST['key2'], .....)) {
   // handle this error, you don't have the correct inputs
} else {

   // Validate inputs

   // Escape inputs prior to inserting into database
   $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userName']);
   ...
   ...

   // Your queries
}
```

Comment: i tried to if (!isset($_POST['userName'],...) part and this enters into if statement and i have used mysql_real_escape_string but anything does not change.

Answer (score 0):

check in the page whose form action is this page if

name attribute of the input tags in that page are same as what you are trying to retrieve here.

like

```
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='register' />
</form>
```

in register.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   // value in quotes should be same as name attribute in input tag
    $username=$_POST["username"] 
    ..
}
```

-- Update

```
<form method ='post' action='register.php' >
    <input type="text" name="UserMail" id="UserMail" size="30" />   
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="UserName" size="30" />  
    <input type="text" name="lname" id="UserSurname" size="30" />   
    <input type="text" name="telephone" id="UserTel" size="30" />   
    <input type="password" name="userPassword" id="UserPassword" size="30" />
     </form
```

and in register page

```
if(isset($_POST['UserMail']))
{
   $mail =mysql_real_escape_strings($_POST['UserMail']);
 }
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
{
   $mail =mysql_real_escape_strings($_POST['fname']);
 }
 if(isset($_POST['lname']))
 {
   $mail =mysql_real_escape_strings($_POST['lname']);
 }
```

Comment: i have rewritten name attributes in my html page but i have still same error.

Comment: Have you enclosed the variables in `<form method='post' action='register.php' >`

Comment: yes i have enclosed that form : <form id="form5" action="register.php" method="get"> but my method part is different from you.

Comment: Your method is `get change it to post method="post"`

Comment: i have changed my method from get to post but there are still same errors.

Comment: can you post the whole code of that page. and is there a leading '{' in register page

Comment: The error is the name attribute of the input tags and the $_POST are not matching and method should be post

Comment: '{' is my error. i have set that. i have done name values name tags and $_POST. for example: <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" size="30" />  and $_POST['UserName']

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="UserName" size="30" />
```

Change `name="fname"` to `name="UserName"`.
Do the same for other fields.

`$_POST` uses `name` attribude, not `ID`.

---

You have to check if your `$_POST` variables are set by using [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Example with **`isset()`**:

```
if(isset($_POST['UserName'])) $username = $_POST['UserName'];
else die("Username variable is not set.");
```

Example with **`empty()`**:

```
if(!empty($_POST['UserName'])) $username = $_POST['UserName'];
else die("Username variable is empty.");
```

---

Another thing you should have on your mind is that you should escape your strings before using it in a SQL query by using [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Example:

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['UserName']);
```

You also might want to use the [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) in combination with escaping.

Comment: when i used if(isset($_POST['UserName'])) $username = $_POST['UserName'];
else die("Username variable is not set."); it writes die message.

Comment: do you think that i have a mistake about input tags in my html page ?  my input tags:  <input type="text" name="UserMail" id="UserMail" size="30" />  <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" size="30" />  <input type="text" name="UserSurname" id="UserSurname" size="30" />  <input type="text" name="UserTel" id="UserTel" size="30" />    <input type="password" name="UserPassword" id="UserPassword" size="30" />

Comment: @rockenpeace Yes. I've edited my answer with the solution, take a look at the top of it.

Comment: i have changed name attributes according to $_POST names. For example, name="UserName" but it still gives die message.